# Sending POST JASON via PHP CURL not working

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

Using CURL in PHP.  Trying to create a report so I need to use POST

Here is my code

```
function httpRequest($url, $post = '', $header = null, &$status = null) {

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
  ]);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
  if ($post) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  if ($post) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
  if ($header) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

  $out = curl_exec($ch);

  if (curl_errno($ch)) exit('Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
  if ($status !== null) $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  return $out;
}
```

when I call

```
 httpRequest('https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/reports/2021-06-30/reports, '{"reportTypes":"GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA","marketplaceIds":"XXX"}', $header);
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Status code 400: {
"errors": [
{
  "code": "InvalidInput",
  "message": "One or more required parameters missing",
  "details": "reportTypes;"
  }
 ]
}
```

All my curl GET functions work but I cant get POST to work

CURL POST to create a listings report.  Messed with the CURL function and nothing is working for me